# How can I remove non-matching values from two lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have two lists of lists of mass spec data, in the format [time, intensity, m/z]. This data is obtained through pymzml, by scanning through a mass spectrum and extracting the values for two m/z values from each timepoint.

I want to normalise the intensity values of one list to the other, e.g:

```
IS = [1, 10, 122.076], [2, 40, 122.076], [3, 60, 122.076]...
AN = [1, 30, 146.117], [2, 80, 146.117], [3, 90, 146.117]...
```

Where the intensity (middle) values in IS would then be divided by the intensity values in AN, to create normalised intensities as such:

```
IS_arr = np.asarray(IS_intensity)
    AN_arr = np.asarray(AN_intensity)
    Norm_arr = np.divide(IS_arr, AN_arr2)
    Norm_list = list(Norm_arr)
```

Unfortunately, while the time values for each list are the same, the two m/z values are not detected at the same timepoints all the time. For example, at time 6, IS may be detected but AN not.

This is creating an issue when normalising via numpy as obviously when converted to arrays, they aren't the same shape.

Is there a way to compare the two lists/arrays and remove any rows that do not contain matching time values?

I am able to split the lists into individual lists, and I am able to resize the array once converted. However, this leads to meaningless data as the timepoints are not aligned once normalised.

This would also need to be done while in a list of lists or array, as the whole row would need to be removed - just removing the non-matching values would worsen the data even more.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the work to [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

IS = np.array([[1, 10, 122.076], [2, 40, 122.076], [3, 60, 122.076]])
AN = np.array([[1, 30, 146.117], [3, 80, 146.117], [4, 90, 146.117]])

columns = ["time", "intensity", "m/z"]
df_IS = pd.DataFrame(IS, columns=columns)
df_AN = pd.DataFrame(AN, columns=columns)

df = pd.merge(df_IS, df_AN, on="time", suffixes=("_IS", "_AN"))
df["intensity_norm"] = df["intensity_IS"] / df["intensity_AN"]
```

```
>>> df
   time  intensity_IS   m/z_IS  intensity_AN   m/z_AN  intensity_norm
0   1.0          10.0  122.076          30.0  146.117        0.333333
1   3.0          60.0  122.076          80.0  146.117        0.750000
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your needs, you can improve your data management by storing it in tuples or even a dictionary as follows:

Tuple:

```
var 1 = (time, intensity, m/z)
and so one for each unit
```

Dictionary:

```
var1 = {'time'=x, 'intensity'=y, 'm/z'=z}
and so on for each unit.
```

After that, you can include all units/variables in a list (or separate lists) where you can sort/filter your data.

If that answer doesn't fit your need, please post an example input and desired output so we can understand more clearly.